# Why was my comparison question closed?

Tags: support, closed-questions

A while back, I asked a question about [how the Raspberry Pi compares](https://superuser.com/questions/592793/how-does-the-raspberry-pi-stack-up), but it was closed as "Not Constructive". I don't see how. I'll break it down:

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit in our Q&A format.

Huh. Why?

> We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or expertise,

Ummm. What? It's a comparison question. I'm asking for stats. Unless I'm an idiot, stats *are* facts.

> but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.

How? I'm *not* asking which is better. I'm asking how they *compare*.

> If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, visit the help center for guidance.

It looks good to me. That's *why* I asked.

> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit your question or leave a comment.

It *already* fits the rules from what I can tell!

Can anyone shed some light here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to ask a good question is to have it about *a real problem*. Lets pick this question apart.

From your question

> "This hypothetical setup would be a vanilla Debian installation with
>   nginx and such."

From the [[FAQ]](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

> you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______
>   happened?”

Also from your question

> How does this setup compare between a Raspberry Pi (maybe a couple of
>   them for balancing), a desktop used for everyday tasks, and a
>   commodity rack mounted server?

What sort of desktop? What sort of loads? Where do we reasonably expect a bottleneck ?

Would we be comparing a modern core i7, a still reasonably competent and realistically retired c2d?

What sort of rackmount server? A brand new 4u server running dual xeons and inconceivably huge amounts of ram?  someone's old alpha we pulled out of a university dumpster>

In short, you've asked a hypothetical questions about hypothetical hardware setups, and expect it to be treated as a real question.

The 35 dollar + S&H question I'd ask is *why not try it?*. Its one hell of a geek toy and cheap enough to buy after mowing a lawn or two. Throw on a copy of raspian, try your setup, and see if its good enough for your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Because it is a comparison question and we do not field comparison questions. It's the same as asking for a review. In this case the terms would be interchangeable and both equally valid in reason to close.

It was either this or too localised. Or too broad now.

You are asking about a hypothetical which ends up throwing in guesses and discussion about how one tweak or change in configuration would compare.